# JS Promise in LWC returning in catch block despite success response from Server side Apex

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, promises

```
 handleAddRows(event) {
        if (this.selectedSubjTemplate.length > 0) {
            this.isLoadingModal = true;
            createRecord({ quoteId: this.quoteRec, subjTemplates: this.selectedSubjTemplate })
                .then(operation => {
                    if(operation ==  'success'){
                        this.isLoadingModal = false;
                        this.showToast("Success", "Added successfully!", "success");
                        //console.log('@@Rows added::'+result);
                        this.closeModal();        
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('## error in creating records: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                    this.showToast("Error", "Error in creating record!", "error");
                })
        }
```

Despite receiving a success response from Apex method, the promise is executing the catch block.

Comment: Please make sure to use the tools in the editor to format your code. Thanks!

Comment: Sure David. Any idea about the issue?

Comment: could you also share the error thats getting printed by the catch block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an error occurs at any point in the `then` handler, this will cause the `catch` block to execute. That means if there's a problem with `showToast` or `closeModal`, you'll get to the `catch` block all the same. To understand why, consider the alternative form of your code:

```
async handleAddRows(event) {
    if (this.selectedSubjTemplate.length > 0) {
        this.isLoadingModal = true;
        try {
            const operation = await createRecord({ quoteId: this.quoteRec, subjTemplates: this.selectedSubjTemplate });
            if (operation == 'success') {
                this.isLoadingModal = false;
                this.showToast("Success", "Added successfully!", "success");
                //console.log('@@Rows added::'+result);
                this.closeModal();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('## error in creating records: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            this.showToast("Error", "Error in creating record!", "error");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, even with a successful return, if there's a problem further down the line, you'll still hit the same exception handler (this has tripped me up more than once, to be sure).

Make sure that you're testing your code for any exceptions, such as undefined variables, accessing null objects, etc. You might consider using `finally` to close the modal, or something else. Try to avoid doing any heavy logic in the `then` handler that might throw errors.

You can read more about this behavior [here](https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling).

Comment: Worth a link to something like [this](https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling)?

Comment: Thank you! @sfdcfox showToast function was the culprit here.

Comment: @PhilW Definitely. Added it in for future visitors.